# Sending SOAP response back and then continue executing the method?

Tags: java, ruby, web-services, soap

I have a Ruby application which consumes a web service that is implemented in Java. The Ruby application basically invokes a method in my web service, and returns a string after its completion.

I don't want it to wait for the method to finish and return a string, instead, it should close the connection and free the worker so that it could start the same process for a different set of input.

Any ideas how I can do this? Is there a way that the method could send back the response 'OK' first and then keep executing?

Comment: You need to show a sample of your code; It's better that we modify what you've written then us write totally unrelated code and you try to shoe-horn it into place.

Comment: Why don't you look into the [Thread](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html) class? Look at the [example](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html#method-c-new) for `new`. That seems like it'd be the appropriate way for your code to implement this.